# Balls and Baskets Problem Algorithm?

Tags: algorithm

Let's say there are N people and all these people have 1 basket and unlimited balls.
They can throw a ball to others' baskets.

We let them throw their balls to others' baskets and we come up with a scenario like that :

'A' person's basket
Balls from E, F, G, I, K, L, M, P

'B' person's basket
Balls from A, C, E, F, K, T, R, Z

'C' person's basket
Balls from ......

etc...

so I want to design an algorithm to find out which ones are friends. For example if A, C, D and E are friends they should throw their balls to each others' baskets. But at the same time they can throw some random stranger's basket too.

I know it is an optimization problem, there is not a spesific solution but I'm open to any idea to start over.

Thanks.

Comment: So what is the assignment? Come up with an algorithm to guess which people are friends?

Comment: What have you tried so far?  People will help if you get stuck, but you need to start somewhere.

Comment: How many balls from a specific person have to show up before they are considered "friendly"? Does symmetry  matter; that is, are A and B only friends if A's basket has a ball from B and B's basket has a ball from A?

Comment: Are you looking for complete subgraphs of your graph (or rather, complete subgraphs of of the undirected graph formed by placing an edge connecting any two people who both have balls in each others' buckets)? If so, the magic words you want to search for are "clique-finding".

Comment: it is not an assignment actually just a part of a project. So you can guess it is not related to balls or baskets of course.

Comment: question is to find the groups of people (at least 4 or 5 for example) who are friends.

Comment: there is no limit of balls 1 common ball is a friendship but 9 common balls is a a little more friendship. I want to find the possible groups of friends.

Comment: I'm not talking about a certain friendship here. I dont care if A and B are friends or not but if there is a group of people A, B , K, L who are all throw the balls each other's basket then I want to find them. Find groups of such.

Comment: by the way thanks steve.
im now searching for clique finding it may be very useful.

Answer (score 1):

Friends will probably give each other a ball - there's a great starting point.

```
for x,y in people:
    if (x contains y && y contains x):
        x & y are friends.
    else:
        skip.
```

Rough pseudocode, write it in what you know.

That's only the beginning though, you should probably look at clusters of friends to weed out coincidences and add in forgotten friends.